# VB.NET - Returning dynamic class value from function

Tags: vb.net, list, class

The issue that I am having is in the following code.  The function works for the ControlCaption entity class but I have to copy and paste it for each of the other entity classes that I need to read from and then change ControlCaption to the new class name (I hate duplicating code when I don't have to).  Because there is also a function for Updating/Inserting values I had tried to set a public object equal to the class (i.e. Public SomeClass as Object = New ControlCaption) but the IDE complained about it.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function SelectList(Optional ByVal SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & DatabaseName) As List(Of ControlCaption)
    Dim strConnectionString As String = ConnectionString()      '--Creates the connection string
    Dim intLineNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim InfoList As New List(Of ControlCaption) '--List of classes being returned

    Try
        If DatabaseType = SQLServer Then    '--User indicated previously that a SQL Server was being used
            Using myConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Using myCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLString, myConnection)
                    Using myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
                        Do While myReader.Read
                            InfoList.Add(New ControlCaption()) '--Add a new element to the list

                            '--The next couple of lines need System.Reflection to be imported to work
                            '--The following for statement goes through each property in a class and assigns
                            '--the database value with the same name to the property. (Required to use entity classes)
                            Dim TheObject As New ControlCaption
                            Dim TheType As Type = TheObject.GetType()
                            Dim Properties() As PropertyInfo = TheType.GetProperties()
                            For Each Prop As PropertyInfo In properties
                                Try
                                    If UCase(Prop.Name) <> "ITEM" Then
                                        If TypeOf (myReader.Item(Prop.Name)) Is DateTime Then
                                            '--Convert value to date
                                            InfoList(InfoList.Count - 1).Item(Prop.Name) = CDate(IIf((myReader.Item(Prop.Name).ToString & String.Empty) = vbNullString, "1/1/1900", myReader.Item(Prop.Name).ToString))
                                        Else
                                            InfoList(InfoList.Count - 1).Item(Prop.Name) = myReader.Item(Prop.Name).ToString & String.Empty
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                            Next
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using

                If myConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    myConnection.Close()
                End If

                Return InfoList
            End Using
        ElseIf DatabaseType = AccessDatabase Then
            Using myConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Using myCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLString, myConnection)
                    Using myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
                        Do While myReader.Read
                            InfoList.Add(New ControlCaption())

                            Dim TheObject As New ControlCaption
                            Dim TheType As Type = TheObject.GetType()
                            Dim Properties() As PropertyInfo = TheType.GetProperties()
                            For Each Prop As PropertyInfo In properties
                                Try
                                    If UCase(Prop.Name) <> "ITEM" Then
                                        If TypeOf (myReader.Item(Prop.Name)) Is DateTime Then
                                            InfoList(InfoList.Count - 1).Item(Prop.Name) = CDate(IIf((myReader.Item(Prop.Name).ToString & String.Empty) = vbNullString, "1/1/1900", myReader.Item("DateModified").ToString))
                                        Else
                                            InfoList(InfoList.Count - 1).Item(Prop.Name) = myReader.Item(Prop.Name).ToString & String.Empty
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                            Next
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using

                If myConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    myConnection.Close()
                End If

                Return InfoList
            End Using
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I feel like there's got to be a way of making this function accept any class but I haven't figured out a way yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?  Any improvement suggestions would help also.

Thank you.

---

For anyone interested, here is the final code that was produced:

```
Public Function SelectList(Of EntityClass As New)(Optional ByVal SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & DatabaseName) As List(Of EntityClass)
    Try
        Dim Entities As New List(Of EntityClass)()
        Using Connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLString, Connection)
                Connection.Open()
                Using Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim Properties = GetType(EntityClass).GetProperties()
                    Do While Reader.Read
                        Dim Entity = CreateEntity(Of EntityClass)(Reader, Properties)
                        Entities.Add(Entity)
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Return Entities
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Private Function CreateEntity(Of PassedEntity As New)(ByVal reader As DbDataReader, ByVal properties As PropertyInfo()) As PassedEntity
    Dim Entity As New PassedEntity()
    For Each _Property As PropertyInfo In properties
        If _Property.Name.ToUpper() = "ITEM" Then Continue For

        Dim value = reader.Item(_Property.Name)
        _Property.SetValue(Entity, value, Nothing)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Make it generic

Comment: Are you sure that optional parameter with default value in your method is compiled? I afraid that default value should be constant value

Comment: Classes are fairly new to me in VB.NET.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like good candidate for generics with "New" constraints.
"New" constraint will give possibility to create new instance of given type.

```
Public Function SelectList(Of T As New)(query As String ) As List(Of T)
    Dim list As New List(Of T)()

    ' Somewhere in the rows loop
        Dim item = New T()
        ' Fill properties
        list.Add(item)

    Return list 
End Function
```

If you want to avoid duplicated code, then you can remove some duplication by using `DbDataReader` class, which is a base class for both `SqlDataReader` and `OleDbDataReader`.

```
Private Function CreateEntity<(Of T As New)(reader As DbDataReader, 
                                            properties As PropertyInfo()) As T
    Dim entity As New T()
    For Each property As PropertyInfo In properties
        If property.Name.ToUpper() = "ITEM" Then Continue For

        Dim value = reader.Item(property.Name)
        ' Should work if property type is correspondent .NET type of sql column type
        ' For null values property should be of Nullable type
        property.SetValue(entity, value)
        ' If not - use your logic
    Next       
End Function
```

Then you can use this function in reading logic. Notice that you don't need to run `Type.GetProperties()` in every loop - get it once for the type and reuse same collection

```
Public Function SelectList(Of T As New)(query As String ) As List(Of T)
    Dim entities As New List(Of T)()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As new SqlCommand(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim properties = GetType(T).GetProperties()
                Do While reader.Read()
                    Dim entity = CreateEntity(reader, properties)
                    list.Add(entity)
                Loop
            End Using
        ' No need for closing connection explicitly - End Using - will handle it
        End Using
    End Using

    Return entities 
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I thought I was doing good with the transition between VB6 and VB.NET but there appears to be a lot of stuff I have missed and need to learn ASAP.  Between you, Fabio, and a couple of things for DJV I was able to get it working.  The reduction in the size of the code is AMAZING.  Thanks guys.

`code`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the function parameter to type `Object`, you then can pass it any object type.  For example:

```
    Public Function SelectList(Optional ByVal SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & DatabaseName) As List(Of Object)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is one of the things I tried before asking for help but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make it generic. Just return a list of objects which you can instantiate.

It would be called like this:

```
Dim myFoo As List(Of Foo) = SelectList(Of Foo)("Select * FROM Foo")
```

Here is the new code

```
Public Function SelectList(Of T As New)(Optional ByVal SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & DatabaseName) As List(Of T)
    Dim InfoList As New List(Of T) '--List of classes being returned
    Dim connectionType = If(DatabaseType = SQLServer, connectionType.MsSql, connectionType.MsAccess)
    Try
        Using myConnection = getConnection(connectionType, ConnectionString())
            myConnection.Open()
            Using myCommand = getCommand(connectionType, SQLString, myConnection)
                Using myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
                    Do While myReader.Read
                        Dim TheObject As New T()
                        InfoList.Add(TheObject) '--Add a new element to the list
                        Dim TheType As Type = TheObject.GetType()
                        Dim Properties() As PropertyInfo = TheType.GetProperties()
                        For Each Prop As PropertyInfo In Properties
                            Try
                                If UCase(Prop.Name) <> "ITEM" Then
                                    Prop.SetValue(TheObject, Convert.ChangeType(myReader.Item(Prop.Name), Prop.PropertyType), Nothing)
                                End If
                            Catch
                            End Try
                        Next
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
            Return InfoList
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Oh, wait, a LOT of other things changed here too! I couldn't bear the thought of you duplicating the function almost as much as you duplicating the query code, so I made a single loop. Use these functions to create `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` objects, since the rest of the code is the same (and they are really just calling functions available to those interfaces anyway).

```
Private Function getConnection(connectionType As ConnectionType, connectionString As String) As IDbConnection
    Select Case connectionType
        Case ConnectionType.MsSql
            Return New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Case ConnectionType.MsAccess
            Return New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function

Private Function getCommand(connectionType As ConnectionType, commandString As String, connection As IDbConnection) As IDbCommand
    Select Case connectionType
        Case ConnectionType.MsSql
            Return New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
        Case ConnectionType.MsAccess
            Return New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function

Private Enum ConnectionType
    MsSql
    MsAccess
End Enum
```

(If you were ever to add another connection type, it would be simple as long as it implements these interfaces).

The property setting code can be simplified, and assuming the date is in a standard format, only one line is need to set all the properties

```
Prop.SetValue(TheObject, Convert.ChangeType(myReader.Item(Prop.Name), Prop.PropertyType), Nothing)
```

Also, you can see that there is no reason to create *two* `ControlCaption` objects there...

Lastly, you don't need to explicitly close the connection because you correctly have it in a using block already.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Thank you for your help.  This works great also.